# не выводятся картинки при преобразовании в XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть xml ,преаброзую её в xslt,в DOM структуре появляется список и картика с атрибутом src но этот атрибут(src) пуст?  и в результате вместо картинки выводятся пустые квадратики.Помогите исправить

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="template.xsl"?><!---->
  <document>
   <list type="slider">
    <item>
     <image uri="1.jpg" title="image-1" />
     <paragraph>abrakadabra</paragraph>
    </item>
    <item>
     <image uri="2.jpg" title="image-2" />
     <paragraph>bla-bla-bla</paragraph>
    </item>
    <item>
     <image uri="3.jpg" title="image-3" />
     <paragraph>whooo-AAAA</paragraph>
    </item>
  </list>
</document>
```

само преобразование

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="document">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="list"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
    <img src="{.}"/>
<img>
 <xsl:attribute name="src">img/<xsl:value-of select='img' /> 
</xsl:attribute>
</img><!-- и так не работает -->
    <span>
        <xsl:value-of select="paragraph"/>
    </span>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="document">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="list" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
      <img>
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select="image/@uri" />
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:attribute name="title">
          <xsl:value-of select="image/@title" />
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:attribute name="width">150</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="height">150</xsl:attribute>
      </img>

      <span>
        <xsl:value-of select="paragraph" />
      </span>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: не подскажите а как задать картинке размер ?(непосредственно в xslt шаблоне) пишу и не срабатывает 

  <xsl:attribute-set name="src">
  <xsl:attribute name="width">150</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="height">150px</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

Comment: @cheburashkarf Добавил.